# git clone does a master branch checkout

Tags: git

I have been trying to understand git. I have a question.

I am using `Git Extensions` on windows. When I do `clone a repository` using git extenstions does it automatically do a checkout of master branch as well into by working directory?

Suppose after doing `git clone` I want to switch to a specific `tag` how do I do that?

Comment: Default branch (often master) depends on the repository's configuration. If you want to clone a tag, you could clone the repo and reset it to the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is standard behavior of `git clone` to create an initial branch (`master`) from the remote repository's active branch.  From the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) for `git clone`:

> Clones a repository into a newly created directory, creates remote-tracking branches for each branch in the cloned repository (visible using git branch -r), and creates and checks out an initial branch that is forked from the cloned repository’s currently active branch.

A tag in Git is similar to an alias to a commit.  To switch to a specific tag you can use `git checkout` in the same way you would checkout a `<SHA-1>` hash of a given commit:

```
git checkout <name-of-tag>
```

Comment: Also, `git clone -b <tag>` will just clone that tag and check it out in a detached head state without checking out master.